# How to restrict SQL columns based on id of requester?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my application a requester has permission to query only certain columns. The columns may differ between requesters. The where clause changes between requests so that the rows returned change with each query. What is the best way to handle this access control? Should I use an array to store permitted columns and then do the check in my application?

I'm on PostgreSQL 9.x

Example:
We have medical professionals that can access records of patients but not all medical professionals should be able to access all information. They try to request arbitrary information about any patient (which have a uid) but we should enforce access controls.

So say the info is name, date of birth, blood type and illness

Doctor A has permission for all fields
Doctor B can see everything except blood type
Administrator can only see name and date of birth
Hematologist can only see blood type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement option 2, I would have a column permissions table something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE ColumnPerms
(
    user_or_role      Varchar(50),
    table_name        Varchar(50),
    column_name       Varchar(50),
)

CREATE INDEX ix_Columnperms(user_or_role, table_name)
```

The *table_name* column is to allow this functionality to be implemented on more than just a single table in your app:  if it's unnecessary, don't use it.   You could adopt the convention that role names start with a '@' character, to ensure that there is no collision with user names.

Now, when you build your dynamic query, you can do something like

```
SELECT column_name 
  FROM ColumnPerms 
 WHERE user_or_role = '@manager'
   AND table = 'Payroll'
   AND column_name IN ('first_name', 'last_name', 'hire_date', 'base_salary', 'bonus')
```

(the IN clause should include EVERY column potentially to be returned).

The result of this query is a list of the column names *that user* is allowed to see.  Just iterate through it to build your column list when constructing the dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you could take:

1. Use Postgres to enforce the security using column level permissions for each user (or user role).  Look at the syntax for GRANT here:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html
2. Build dynamic sql statements limiting what rows may be returned for each user.   This could become pretty tedious if there are many users, or many different column combinations.  You'll probably want to keep a table of user ids, and "selectable" table, column names for building the query statement.   If you want this generalized to many different queries, you could either build them on top of a table-returning function that does the column filtering, or revert to option 1.

For option 1, make sure that columns used in the join are selectable...

Comment: GRANT seems geared toward DB "users" while my "users" are users of the application. Specifically the current user of my application is going to be fixed once I open a connection to the db and I don't think it is a good idea to be creating many short lived connections.

Comment: That reduces the options to number 2, then.

Comment: As for your second option, what is the schema of the "selectable" table? Does each row consist of a boolean for each column? I can do work on the application side. Is my initial suggestion of using arrays to store the columns and doing the check in the app ill-conceived?

Comment: Are the columns what the user can have in the WHERE clause, or what they can return from the query, or both?
Either way, I would attempt this is in a db function, with input parameters being the WHERE clause filters as an HSTORE, and the id (or whatever you are using) of the requester. Within the function you could then dynamically construct the query as suggested in option 2.

Comment: I don't think writing a db function to do this filtering would be too much work, but the stickier points are going to be rigorous testing, and keeping the list of changing permissions up to date.

Is your medical data example a real one? That seems rather concerning, considering that any corner case bugs in the query filters could expose user medical data to people that should not see it.

Comment: @bma    I absolutely agree.   If you go this route, you should definitely test the crap out of it before it goes into production.    If the number of use cases is small, you might want to have a number of pre-packaged views that that you select from, instead.